# Calculating amount of memory a CPP program uses

Tags: c++, windows

```
struct Player
{
    char* nameptr;
    float x=0, y=0, z=0;
    float angle = 0.0;
    int health = 100;
    int armour = 0;
    int weapon = 0;
};
Player players[100];
```

Hi, int is 4 bytes, float is also 4 bytes. pointer is also four bytes. So basically 8 * 4=32 bytes.
3200 bytes is approx 3 KB.
So does this program after the line where we declare the array uses 3 KB RAM?
Thanks

Comment: `std::cout << sizeof(players) << std::endl;` knows exactly how much space the array uses.

Comment: Probably not.   A certain amount of memory is also consumed for the instructions that will operate on the various structures, for startup code (including initialisation of standard streams like `std::cout` and `std::cin`), etc.    Also, your 100 instances of `Player` are probably not useful unless the `nameptr` members are each initialised to point at *something*, and that *something* consumes memory in some form.

Answer (score 2):

For your struct, I'd say the calculations are ok, maybe Pointer can be 8 byte for x64.

You should also be aware of [`#pragma pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=msvc-160), which might change things. I'm assuming you haven't used that or an equivalent compiler switch.

Also, things will change when you `new` the players on the heap instead of create them on the stack. The heap has some overhead and that overhead depends on whether you build a release build or a debug build. It also depends whether you run it under a debugger or not.

But, there is more to just calculating these numbers. On a Windows system, the program will

- load `ntdll.dll`
- load `kernelbase.dll`
- load `kernel32.dll`
- load `wow64.dll` if compiled as 32 bit
- load the executable
- maybe load even more DLLs like `msvcrt` when using the Microsoft compiler
- create a stack of 1 MB size (IMHO that depends on the compiler settings, but 1 MB is the default)
- create a default heap of 1 MB size

so the total memory used is much higher.

Next, not all of the memory needs to be in RAM. Parts of it may be swapped to disk and that may change at any time. If you want to measure it, have a look at the "Working set size" metric (which is a quite bad metric, BTW).

So, the real answer is a new question: what do you actually mean by asking "how much RAM is used"? Why do you want to know that and what do you want to do with the number that is the result?

Comment: It is to make an NPC program for a game(vice city multiplayer). So in this program i need to store the Name, health, position co-ordinates and weapon ids. So I thought i could use arrays. There is 100 players maximum.(99 excluding the npc). So i want to create an array and memory should also be less consumed, because the user might ran lot of copies of the same program. ie. some 10 npcs with different ids.

Comment: @HabiHaris: that's fine. Do you tell your customers "When you look at Task Manager, you'll see 3200 bytes of memory being used"? That would be wrong.